# Is BerkeleyDB open sourced? Where can I find its source code?

Tags: berkeley-db

It seems like BerkeleyDB is acquired by Oracle which does not publish the source code on its web?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sleepycat was acquired by Oracle in 2006. The product continues to be available under the original open source license and continues to be enhanced. You can find the source code on [Oracle's web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) here in both .zip and .tar formats. The distribution includes the full source code.

Just FYI: Oracle has many open source products. Source code is freely available for all of them.

Disclaimer: I'm the Product Manager for Berkeley DB and have been working with the product for over 7 years, so I'm a little biased. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking it's "source available" rather than "open source", in the sense that contributions from the community are not (to my knowledge) elicited or accepted, right? Happy to be corrected if I'm wrong on my terminology there.

Comment: We're both, IMHO. All of BDB's source code is available and is part of the download package on Oracle's OTN web site -- no secret sauce here. We also accept contributions from the community -- there is a process for that. However, we do maintain control of the source tree, if that's what you're referring to. If you have a contribution or suggestion, please let us know. We're always happy to hear from our users.

Comment: -1 Having to create an account (which takes forever) in order to download the source is *NOT FREE*.

Comment: @DDrmmr: well, actually it `is` free, as in, you didn't pay for it.

Comment: You can download Berkeley-DB without creating an account using `wget` on a linux machine. I think direct link should also work: 

`wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-6.2.23.NC.tar.gz`

Comment: It you are worried about using open source code, you should consider using lmdb (Lightning Memory-Mapped Database) it is part of the OpenLDAP project, so i think it is open sourced. I think it is also faster then Berkeley DB. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database

Comment: Copy the address in the downloads page and remove the "otn" part to download without creating an account.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the source code on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/berkeley-db).

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to download the source without creating an account.